# Salesforce product image in listview & detail in Salesforce commerce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-commerce-cloud

As of now i am fetching product list and product detail using on Postman using GET method.
Product Detail using below GET request.

```
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/sobjects/Product2/01t5J0000015fA2s5I
```

It does not return product media field, While we need to fetch product image.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user you're connecting with. Profiles, permissions sets. I suspect the field is not marked readable so API skips it. Is the field "normal" or coming from a managed package? You may need a license too if it's part of a package.